# ML bound for Massive MIMO

Tags: mimo, maximum-likelihood-estimation

How can one estimate the ML bound for Massive Mimo detection with 128 transmitting antenna and 128 receiving antennas using 4 QAM modulation?

I have seen for a 8 by 8 system it is possible to use K-best detection but for a 128 by 128 system I am not really convinced that K-best detection is the way to go.